# Grouping for mean

Tags: r

```
month  v1   v2   v3
    1   1    4   52
    1   5    2    1
    2   4  220   45
    2   6   12   21
    3   7   22   45
    3   8   22   36
```

I am pretty new with R. I have dataframe with date and few variable. I want to calculate the col average by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
summarise(group_by(data, month), mean(v1, na.rm = TRUE), mean(v2, na.rm = TRUE), mean(v3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I was trying the same but it give NA when i use the data.frame and it is not working when i converted it to numeric using as.matrix

Comment: I edited it, it shouldn't return NA now.

Comment: thank you for help!! still i got an error saying the argument is not numeric. (I think as my data set are in dataframe i am not able to calculate mean)

Comment: Use `class(data$v1)` to check what datatype it is. If it is stored as character, you can convert it to numeric with `data$v1 <- as.numeric(data$v1)`. If it is stored as factor, you can convert it to numeric with `data$v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$v1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `data.table` as it is incredibly fast, faster than `dplyr` or `base R`.

```
library(data.table)

meanCalc    <-  DT[ , .(mean = mean(v1, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(month)]
```

You can add more columns to separate by if you add `by = .(month, *other column*, ....)`

You can choose a different column by switching `v1` into `v2` in `mean(v1, ...)`